# How to wait until an element disappears in Capybara?

Tags: ruby, capybara, site-prism

Note: by the time I finished writing up this question, the solution presented itself, but maybe others may find this useful, or could offer alternatives.

I have read the following articles:

- this thread:
  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ruby-capybara/Mz7txv1Sm0U
- this poltergeist issue: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/19
- this blog: https://nulogy.com/articles/sleep-is-for-the-weak#.VNVcIrDF8vs
- and this stackoverflow question: [Capybara synchronize with has_no_css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25254584/capybara-synchronize-with-has-no-css)

but still cannot piece together an answer for this particular problem.

I want to wait until an element on the page disappears before continuing.

This element overlaps another element I want to click. When I try to click the target element anyway, I get this error:

```
Capybara::Poltergeist::MouseEventFailed:
   Firing a click at co-ordinates [1006, 322] failed. Poltergeist detected another element with CSS selector 'html body.widgets div#select2-drop-mask.select2-drop-mask' at this position. It may be overlapping the element you are trying to interact with. If you don't care about overlapping elements, try using node.trigger('click').
```

I tried using the `.trigger('click')` and `.trigger(:click)` even, but it seems to have no effect.

Some other things I have tried ('thing' is the disappearing element):

```
@page.wait_until_thing_invisible
 SitePrism::TimeOutWaitingForElementInvisibility:
   execution expired
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more investigation, it seems that the element was rightly not disappearing, because of another issue.

```
     Failure/Error: expect(@page.thing.results.map(&:text)).to include a_string_matching 'search_query'
   expected ["Searching…"] to include (a string matching "search_query")
   Diff:
   @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
   -[(a string matching "search_query")]
   +["Searching…"]
```

That "Searching..." display happens for a split second, and needs to be waited on before trying to click a result.

So now I would like to wait until I don't see the "Searching...", and then continuing with the next click.

I ended up making this while statement:

```
while search_complete = @page.thing.results.map(&:text).reduce.include?('Searching')
  sleep 1
end
```

And this seems to wait until the "Searching..." disappears and the real results appear.

Comment: But the final while loop will result in infinite loop if "Searching" text is persistent.