# Make capybara wait for an element to disappear

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, capybara, poltergeist

After a click on some element I expect a placeholder to disappear and another element to appear after an AJAX call is finished.

```
find(someLocator).click
expect(page).not_to have_css(disappearingPlaceholderLocator)
expect(page).to have_css(appearingElementLocator)
```

The first expectation fails though and the AJAX call is not executed.

I think this is somehow related to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25254584/capybara-synchronize-with-has-no-css) but I just can't figure out how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works when the expectations are flipped.

```
find(someLocator).click
expect(page).to have_css(appearingElementLocator)
expect(page).not_to have_css(disappearingPlaceholderLocator)
```